# Get a product's parent category even if it is accessed directly

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a custom model/block that gets the current product's parent category:

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
{
    public function someFunction()
    {
        $category = $this->getCategory();
        ...
    }
}
```

This custom block is used on a product's page. This works perfectly if the product is accessed via its parent category, e.g.: `domain.com/some-category/my-product.html`. However, if the product is accessed directly (for example through the search) and the URL is like `domain.com/my-product.html`, it doesn't work. All functions from `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` that could be used to retrieve the category return empty values, as if the product wasn't assigned to any categories.

My question is: What is the global way to retrieve a product's category, even if that product is not accessed via its category?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First step: Adjust your expectation slightly — a product in Magento isn't limited to a single category.  Therefore, "a global way to retrieve a product's category" should be "a global way to retrieve a list of any categories the product is in".

You'll need to to

1. Get a reference to a product object
2. Use that product object to get a category collection
3. Run through the collection and pull out the category information you want

If you're on the product page, you can grab the current product from the registry.

```
$product = Mage::registry('product');
```

and then grab a category collection with

```
$c       = $product->getCategoryCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

The `addAttributeToSelect` method ensures you get all the fields you need.

Finally, you can get the individual categories themselves with

```
foreach($c as $category)
{
    var_dump($category->getData());
    var_dump($category->getName());
}
```

You could also grab the first category with

```
$category = $c->getFirstItem();
var_dump($category->getData());
var_dump($category->getName());
```

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks. But I just found out my initial question was wrong. I can access the parent category (or one of them) via `$this->getCategory();` in both "contexts": `domain.com/product.html` as well as `domain.com/category/product.html`.

Comment: I did notice something though: `$categories = $product->getCategoryCollection()->...` always seems to return the parent categories top down, so because I want to use the immediate parent category, I had to use `$categories->getLastItem()`... One small question if you don't mind me asking: In a method of a class that extends `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`, why doesn't `$this` behave exactly the same as `$product = Mage::registry( 'product' );`?

Comment: Sounds like that second question needs more context — try creating a new question instead of using the comments.

Comment: @pragneshrupapara 1. Use fewer question marks.  2. Sounds like a good new question for Stack Overflow or the Magento Stack Exchange.