# how to get immediate parent category from a product

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

i want to get immediate parent category from a current product, i have refereed

[Get a product's parent category even if it is accessed directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735324/get-a-products-parent-category-even-if-it-is-accessed-directly)

but it doesn't help me to find immediate parent category.

please help me

Thank You in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the product as an object, for this example we say your product object is $product. The following should work:

```
$product->getCategory()->getParentCategory();
```

That should return the parent category as an object of Mage_Catalog_Model_Category.

If you don't have the product but say have the product id then the following should be enough to get the product.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
```

But note that a product could have more than one category assigned to in.

If you have more than one category per product you can use getCategoryCollection() to get all the categories.

```
foreach ($product->getCategoryCollection() as $category) {
    $parent_category = $category->getParentCategory();
}
```

Comment: i am using magento 1.7.0.2 and i am getting following error `Fatal error: Call to a member function getParentCategory() on a non-object` and i have create object of product like these `$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);` as you have mention

Comment: ok that error means that the getCategory() is not working. what do you see when you var_dump($product->getData()); or var_dump($product->getCategory());

Comment: is it the product->getData that returns null?

Comment: could you try the getCategoryCollection() function that I have added to my answer

Comment: great so from that parent_id you are able to load the parent category right?

Answer (score 0):

```
$categoryName = '';
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
if(is_array($product->getCategoryIds())) {
    $catId = end($product->getCategoryIds());
    $category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);
    $categoryName = $category->getName();
}
```